# Can't upload image on dockerized gitlab instance

Tags: gitlab-ce

I have a gitlab instance running inside a docker container, when I  change setting in appearance and try to upload icon for sign in/sign up page for example, I got 500 error.
My second problem is I don't have a docker runner register token available in localhost:8080/admin/runners to configure my runner
this is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'localhost'
    container_name: gitlab-ce
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://localhost'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
    volumes:
      - './gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - gitlab
  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    container_name: gitlab-runner    
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - './gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner'
    networks:
      - gitlab

networks:
  gitlab:
    name: gitlab-network
```

expecting to able to change icon/image in appearance setting and able to configure gitlab runner as well